# Is there any way to see an answer that was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete, disciplined-badge

A user posted an answer to my question.  I found the answer useful, although it didn't answer the particular question well.  Being a disciplined user, he deleted his own answer.  The problem is now I want to go back and re-read his answer but it's gone.  Is there any way to recover this data?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it yourself, but users with more than 10k reputation on the target site can.

I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108920/why-is-it-okay-that-this-struct-is-mutable-when-are-mutable-structs-acceptable/8109007#8109007) is the answer you're looking for. I don't see anything here that the answerer would be bothered by reposting, so here you are:

> In this case I would say clearly performance reasons where the deciding factor - the SimpleBitVector32 struct (and its cousin BitVector32) represent a single integer and allow modification of it through helper methods.
>
> The overhead of using a class instead would would kill performance, since you would need an additional pointer into the heap. Using a struct it only needs 4 byte.
>
> If this struct was immutable you couldn't change the integer it represents - so each modification method would have to return a new SimpleBitVector32, which again is a performance problem.

Comment: I guess I have a reason to renew my addiction.  Damn, thought i kicked it...  P.S. thanks for the C+P

Comment: You're already 9.44% the way there!