# View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, 10k-tools

> *Note*: This is a followup to a [followup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125820/is-it-acceptable-to-unupvote-and-unaccept-an-answer-to-delete-a-question) question (original [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125818/question-voluntarily-removed-by-its-author-with-an-answer-that-was-upvoted-and)), so it is likely missing information on its own to provide the detail necessary. In the spirit of reducing duplication on the SE servers, please see the related questions if you have questions.

I realize this is a near match for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111961/is-there-any-way-to-see-an-answer-that-was-deleted) question, but given the recent improvements to the rep system on SE and my recent related *though not exactly the same* experience caused by the current shortcomings I'll ask about it again:

Now that users are notified immediately of any loss incurred by deleted/unupvoted/unaccepted answers, it leaves us trying to reconcile the reason for the discrepancies and most users with less than 10K rep (at least most SO users) will likely turn to MSO for resolution. Since you have to have at least 10K rep to view removed questions (and possibly answers) they will be unable to see whether the original question or their original answer is worthwhile to be considered for undeletion. They shouldn't care about unrelated questions or answers so the ability to only allow them to see their contribution and the question they contributed to (or just the question if they asked it themselves) should provide enough information to know whether they feel it should be brought to review.

I realize there are a lot of conditionals in that last statement and bear in mind that I have no idea how hard it would be to implement, but I know I would see benefit from it currently. That tells me that other users *could* benefit from it in the future as well.

Comment: I was pretty sure that you could *always* view your *own* deleted answers, regardless of your reputation level.

Comment: Is what you want this?: The ability, with less than 10k rep, to see deleted questions on which you have a posted answer?

The ability to see your questions/answers that *you* deleted yourself has always been there.

Comment: Cody is correct, unless the parent question is deleted, you can already see your deleted answers - we even link to them in your reputation tab (again, if the parent isn't deleted).  If you're 10k and could see it in either case, we also link.

Comment: @CodyGray - Re-read your initial comment - my mistake. The problem is the question is deleted (hence I cannot see it or my answer on it) so there is no way for me to know whether to bring the question to moderator attention for being removed when it has value. The people who answered a question which was deleted voluntarily by its asker have stake in having it reopened.

Comment: @NickCraver - You found the missing piece to my question... in the case where I answer a question which is later voluntarily removed by its author (such as the one from my initial question), how could I know whether it warrants soliciting mods to reopen it?

Comment: @M.Babcock - unfortunately you can't, show people deleted questions before having high rep has ended in quite a mess in the past, I don't think we'll repeat that anytime soon.  Luckily, at your current rate, 10k isn't that far off.

Comment: @NickCraver - Fair enough. It just seems like it might cause a lot of static in the metas, but if its been tried and didn't work then my solution would likely be worse than the problem itself.

Comment: @NickCraver why don't you put this as an answer? your _tried-and-false_ reasoning makes perfect sense to me and [likely to OP as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k#comment340242_125828 "'if its been tried and didn't work then...'")

Comment: This is a common sense request, why not add it?

Comment: @NickCraver Could you please add an answer detailing that on [the original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)? Just so we have a valid counter argument and can let it come to rest one way or another?

Answer (score 27):

I think that we should always have access to content that *we have authored*. Our own deleted answers and our answers to deleted questions *should* be visible in our profile *answers tab*. Unfortunately this request has already been [explicitly declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/138432).

---

As it is, if we know the ***id*** of our post (question or answer), we should be able to use the ***edit trick*** to get at our content, as [lunboks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130416/138432) suggests in his answer to my [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130415/138432).

For example, as I do not have 10k reputation on Programmers, I get a *Page Not Found* error on [this answer of mine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/what-features-are-there-in-c-and-not-in-java/92333#92333), yet if I strip out the post id (*92333* in this case) and insert it into a URL of the form

```
http://<site>/posts/<post id>/edit
```

then I can still [edit it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/92333/edit) to get access to the content that I authored.

Similarly, I can't read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172089/okay-losers-listen-here) on MSO, (with an id of *172089*) but I can still [suggest an edit to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/172089/edit).

---

Alternatively, [Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/twilight-sparkle) suggests in a comment (since my question had already been closed) that there is a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) which should let you [view deleted questions and your answers to those questions](https://gist.github.com/raw/1361876/423ecda6f3f9f9ae72dae826303ed1ba6e9866d4/deleted.user.js).

See also [How is the editing of deleted posts supposed to behave?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99593/138432)

Comment: The edit trick has been fixed a long while ago AFAIK.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I have added an example of how the *edit trick* works, and just confirmed that it does still work.

Comment: As an aside, your "[edit it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/92333/edit)" gets me (not being the author, of course, and having little rep on Programmers) *"This post is deleted and cannot be edited"*.

Comment: Just thought that I'd say that this _still_ works. Just to clarify, to get at your answer to a question that the author deleted, you need the `answerPostID` from the URL, _not_ the `questionPostID`, where the URL is of the form: `http://<site>/questions/questionPostID/<titleText>/<answerPostID>#<answerPostID>`, and then plug it into Mark's URL above, i.e. `http://<site>/posts/<answerPostID>/edit`

Answer (score 15):

Authors of deleted answers have always been able to see them<sup>*</sup>. As of a few weeks ago, authors of deleted *questions* can now view them as well, regardless of reputation.

As of February 28th, 2017, authors of *answers* to deleted questions can also view them. Kudos to [Konamiman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136880/konamiman) and [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) for making that work after many years of requests!

<sup>*well, not quite *always*, but for several years now.</sup>

Comment: Well, I think Mark's hack doesn't work anymore: *This post is deleted and cannot be edited.*

Comment: You gotta have edit rights for it to work.

Comment: "This is unlikely to change"... Has it changed? [Should I be able to access a deleted question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16841/should-i-be-able-to-access-a-deleted-question)

Comment: Yup, @Zanna - I'll post an update shortly, forgot this was going in.

Comment: Is it possible to view a list of our deleted answers?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes (kind of, only recently deleted answers), see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297927/152859) for steps and screenshots.