# Is there any way for me to access the content of my answer to a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k)

Some time ago I answered a question on Programmers which was subsequently deleted. I referenced my answer in another answer of mine, so I noticed the deletion when the links to that question went stale. I queried this on Programmers meta in my question [Should we be deleting questions which still have valuable answers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/should-we-be-deleting-questions-which-still-have-valuable-answers)

As an adjunct to that question, I asked if there were any way for me, as a <10k user, to access the content of the answer I wrote, but that sub-question was understandably never answered, so I raise it again here.

I would still like to retrieve the content of my hidden answer however. It is frustrating to know that the answer I wrote, which is still available to users with enough reputation is not accessible to me, the author of that answer.

So, is there any way I can access my answer, or do I just have to wait until eventually get 10k rep?

---

I feel that this question is distinct from [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828) in that I am asking if there is **any way** for me to access the content which I have authored (and according to the [SE license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) which I retain copyright to), whereas the other question is about making that content easy to find by making it visible through searches, my answer list or through normal use of the site.

Comment: This same question is on the front page right now...

Comment: Mark, try [installing this user script](https://gist.github.com/raw/1361876/423ecda6f3f9f9ae72dae826303ed1ba6e9866d4/deleted.user.js). It should let you view deleted questions and your answers to those questions.

Comment: @casperOne - Sigh. I *had* read that question, buts since there had been no answers and couldn't actually understand what the questioner was really asking, I thought I would try and pose my own question in a clearer and better thought out way. Did you consider closing that question as a duplicate of this one? It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @MarkBooth There's really no difference between that and this.  Just because something doesn't have any answers doesn't mean that it should be reposted.  Just upvote the existing one.  Or add a bounty.

Comment: @casperOne - Actually it was the fact that I couldn't understand what the questioner was asking that was more of an issue to me. As it is, I think the fact that this question garnered two answers (one as a comment, since it was after closure) within half an hour, when the other question had been languishing with no answer for 10 days simply reinforces my point.

Comment: @MarkBooth If you're using Chrome you just need to click that link, for instructions for other browsers [see here](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info). If you only need to use it once/occasionally, you could also go to the deleted question page and then copy-paste-enter the script into your developer console. (I just made this script for personal use, so it's not exactly well-tested, but it will probably work.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could try a little trick that, with sufficient rep and the post ID known, allows you to view the Markdown source of some deleted posts. The fact is that users can edit some posts that they can't see; the rules [aren't entirely clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave).

Try this link: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/92333/edit

If that doesn't work, you could re-re-raise the issue on the Programmers meta, and ask for a dump of your deleted post. A moderator or 10k user should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks lunboks, that did in fact work for me.

Comment: `A helpful moderator or 10k user should be able to help you out.` There are no helpful moderators on Programmers.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Oh right, thanks for telling me. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Yannis - By the way, do you still hold that opinion? *8')

Comment: Note, since this question has been closed (and thus may be deleted), I have [added an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130421/138432) over at [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125828/138432) containing the relevant information from your answer, just in case this question gets deleted.

Comment: @MarkBooth Nah, that comment is just self deprecating (bad) humour.