# Howto view deleted posts <10k rep

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, privileges, archive

Have you ever wanted to view a deleted question even if you don't have [the required 10k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) for it?

**All you need is the link**:

Take for instance a question from the [deleted meta questions archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-meta-questions-archive) like
[Envelope lighting up arbitrarily and unpredictably](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/envelope-lighting-up-arbitrarily-and-unpredictably).

Take the link:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/
```

Replace `questions` with `posts` and add an `edit` to the end

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/39301/edit/
```

Open that link and you can see the question. That is a bug, right?

I noticed it because I clicked on the edit button of a question that got deleted while I viewed it and I could still open the edit dialog.

PS: I could not get it work for answers though. But maybe someone else has more luck...

Comment: it's a `feature`

Comment: Best feature ever!

Comment: Can we please get this question deleted before anyone from the team sees it?

Comment: @sbi - Too late. Already posted to all devs to see ;)

Comment: It doesn't work for all of them. For example, all [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/82538/edit) gets me is a plain-text message saying `This post is locked and cannot be edited.`

Comment: @Oded: But do they have the rep necessary to see this question once it's deleted? `:)`

Comment: @sbi - Devs have diamonds, they don't need no stinkin' rep

Comment: @Oded: You are disappointing. Why do you think I added a smiley to that question of mine?!

Comment: @sbi Same thing.

Comment: @sbi - It's April 2nd. I lost my sense of humor when the date line crossed over.

Comment: @Oded: You poor sod! What can we do to help you find your lost sense of humor?

Comment: @sbi - A bottle of a good peaty single malt has been known to bring my cheer up.

Comment: For those who're worried that this was uncommon knowledge... It's been known and documented for a good while now; you need to have edit rights on the post you want to view for it to work though. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k