# Users without full edit rights should not be able to submit edits to deleted posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-questions, edit-badges

Having read ChrisForrence's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181760/when-enough-is-enough#comment552979_181760) I have done some experimenting and confirmed that the content of deleted posts can be viewed from the edit page. Furthermore, I'm able to successfully *submit changes* to deleted posts, and they're accepted without the need for approval (I don't have sufficient reputation to edit without approval on Stack Overflow, where I did the testing).

Example:

- [Deleted Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511041/php-bought-out-by-facebook-google-buys-python-and-makes-it-premium-monthly-fe)  (*10k Only - kinda ;-)* )
- [Edit submitted by low-rep user, applied to the question above without approval](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16511041/4)

The posts timeline and revision history are not available, and after submitting an edit you are presented with a 404 page and it doesn't appear in your activity log.  However I was awarded the [Editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor?userid=1091553).

#### Expected behavior

At my rep-level, I can't edit *visible* posts on Stack Overflow without approval (my edits go through the suggested edit review, and become visible on the post only when approved). I would expect *at very least* that the same restrictions would apply for deleted posts - but realistically, expecting folks to review edits on deleted posts sounds like a tremendous waste of time, therefore **I should be prevented from submitting any edits to deleted posts** with the exception of those I've written myself (which I don't need approval for when not deleted).

Furthermore, there's no good reason for me to ever see the edit form when I can't submit it - so attempting to load a URL such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16746220/edit) should result in a 404.

#### More scenarios

- Attempting to edit a locked or migrated deleted question does trigger an error: "*This post is locked and cannot be edited.*"
- Attempting to edit a post on meta (where suggestions aren't allowed at all) triggers an **incorrect error:** "*There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.*" on **non**-deleted posts
- However attempting to edit a deleted post on meta still shows the editing page, though the edit is this time not allowed to be submitted<sup>1</sup> (failing with a nice red box error).

<sup>1  Though the bug that allowed successful submission may have been patched in the meantime rather than this being a difference on metas.</sup>

Comment: Thinking about this further, is this possibly left in to allow the OP to recover from a question ban?

Comment: Well, actually the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22889c52-3a91-4893-b6cb-cb4e2a11c061/view-source) *does* exist. You just can't see it.

Comment: @animuson eeeep sorry to all the 10ks on Stack Overflow, was a bit concerned that would happen!  I was thrown that it didn't appear as a suggestion in my activity :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not sure, for [Shog's answer to that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179769/176080) my Stack *Overflow* account doesn't have the edit privilege and was changing more than tags, therefore my edit shouldn't have been allowed to go through and the badge shouldn't have been awarded if I'm understanding it correctly.  Definitely addresses the first part of my question though, thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. maybe add comment on Shog's answer then alerting him of this?

Comment: @Rory how were you even able to see the deleted question?  Was it deleted while you had the edit form open?

Comment: @Ben I believe you can navigate directly to the edit page for a deleted question if you have the question ID. That was another bug report, which I can't find right now...

Comment: @BenCollins yep that's how I did it, just replace `/questions/` with `/posts/` and then append `/edit` at the end of the URL.  This even works when you have the edit privilege (and therefore would normally be given inline editing instead)

Comment: This sounds like Orc Mischief to me. No seriously, I can already see badge-hunter's trying to abuse the system with this information. It really needs to be addressed...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave/180751#180751

Comment: Related: [howto view deleted posts <10k rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174811/)

Comment: I'm glad to know that I'm not the only one who noticed this!

Comment: @Ben so I take it this bug is scheduled for a fix? I'd say [meta-tag:status-planned] then, or [meta-tag:status-reproduced] in the least. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  yep, and I was headed to this post to do exactly that when you commented.

Comment: @Ben so my telepathic helmet does work after all. ;)