# Why is OP not allowed to edit his/her post deleted by the community moderator?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-questions

From the comments and an answer which are not there now on my previous question :[How can a question deleted by community be undeleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/how-can-a-question-deleted-by-community-be-undeleted) .

I came to know that a post deleted by the "community moderator" cannot be edited by the OP himself/herself if the OP has reputation less than 10k. But why is this so? Most of my posts on Phys.SE are deleted by the "community moderator" and I wanted to improve them. I couldn't. I didn't know that these will be removed from the list of *recently deleted posts* soon. I didn't save their link. Alas they are gone now and I couldn't get an answer to them.
Why is there partiality betweenw high reputed and low reputed users.

---

Not being emotional I am asking why did the designers of SE network take away the right to edit your own post deleted by the "community moderator" from low reputed users? On the other hand one can edit his/her post if it is deleted by some human moderator.

Comment: why i am always left unanswered?

Comment: Don't take it personally, only small part of the feature requests get a real answer i.e. approved or declined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug. See if you can find it:

```
canEdit = (CanSeeDeletedContent || (IsAnswer && isOwner)) && !isSelfDeletedQuestion;
```

This was inadvertently introduced while fixing [another serious bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181813/users-without-full-edit-rights-should-not-be-able-to-submit-edits-to-deleted-pos) - sorry for the confusion!

The [intended behavior is described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#179555) - folks should be able to edit any post they can see, with the *exception* of self-deleted questions.

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I think the bug is in: (IsAnswer && isOwner). It should have been ((IsQuesion || IsAnswer) && isOwner). I don't know whether comments are deleted by comm mod. In the code we could  also have only (isOwnwer); if comments are not deleted by comm mod. Well this is clearly not inadvertently. Creators of SE might have done this deliberately so that one could not edit his question(too much downvoted) after deletion by the community moderator. This way moderators will have to work less. And the scrap of the city will be completely removed.

Comment: time to give a try to [specification pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148855/31260) to make control flow with validation checks manageable

Comment: Do SE team have written different codes for the posts deleted by the "Comm-mod" and by "human-mod"? Or this very code that you say also applies to posts deleted by "human-mod". If the _system_ makes no distinction between human mods and comm mod then why one can edit his/her question if it is deleted by the human-mod?

Comment: The bug breaks both, @anupam.

Comment: I see now, thanks... always good to see pieces of source code! :)

Comment: Must be the mix of lower and upper case i's ;-)

Comment: @Shog9 ~facepalm~ ... that code ... maybe you can't get the logic right with one try, but you could not even get the lower & upper cases right :'( ... my condolence goes to whoever has to maintain it

Comment: uh, you should probably assume that I stripped irrelevant object prefixes there for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Deletion is intended for posts that can't be salvaged, and is considered definitive (from the poster's perspective).

Deletion can be undone, but just in case the deletion itself is considered inappropriate. That is to be judged by moderators or trusted users, who are supposed to be able to handle the distinction.

Comment: Basically, they trust high-rep users and mods. SE respect their choices.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because i know why a post is deleted. My question is:"_Why OP isn't allowed to edit his/her post deleted by the community moderator?_" Although i soon noticed that i was somehow able to edit an answer which is deleted by the community mod but i am sure(as i remember) one is not allowed to edit his question  if it is deleted by the community mod. The weird thing is one can edit his question if it is deleted by the human moderator.