# How to see my answer to a question that was deleted

Tags: feature-request, support, user-accounts

How can I see my answers to a deleted question and is that activity visible under "all actions" in my activity tab?

Comment: AFAIK you can't before you have 10K rep.

Comment: You can see your deleted answers by going to the appropriate direct URL. This is visible for an answer if you got rep from it by digging back through to the original rep events. (The rep reversal entry upon deletion will only give you the URL if you have 10k.) Nothing will be shown in All Actions, although the post may be shown in Deleted Recent Answers.

Comment: @iBug that was the case indeed, until February this year, see [this answer by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179511/152859).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You can

Step 1.

go to user page (default will be Activity tab. If you are not in activity tab, move to it).

Step 2.

Click on answers

[image]

Step 3.

Click on Deleted Recent answers in the bottom

[image]

## Or

Simply follow this link

```
https://<site>.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<user-id>
```

There you can see a list of your deleted answers.

Step 4.

Click on the answer and it will take you to the page

[image]

### Note

If you didn't have 10K rep, you can't see other answers to the question. You will be able to see only the question and your answer.

## Note 2

Old deleted answers will not be listed there.

<strike>There is a time limit which I didn't know exactly but I guess 30 days.</strike>

The time limit is 60 days (Thanks @Aurora0001 for the info)

Comment: Oops. Seems like only [/users/current](/users/current) works but not anything else.

Comment: yes. flags, flair and nothing support `current`