# How can I find my own answer to a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Sometimes questions are deleted, like [this](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/wasnt-a-users-post-deleted-unnecessarily). When someone like me invests some work to answer such a question, it is not nice that the answer isn't readable in my personal activity. Are my now-deleted answers accessible somewhere else?

I've done a little research about this topic and I found an [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and [a more clear one here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). I'm on a beta site and am not a moderator.

On these sites, a situation sometimes occurs when a user joins the site for one question, sees what happens and deletes the account after some time. This will probably delete the question and the answer(s).

Is there a way to lower the barriers to read the deleted answers by me?

I don't want to recreate the question, if the answer is readable it is enough for me.

Comment: For context, what happened here is that the user answered a downvoted question, and a few seconds after they posted their answer the author deleted their account, causing the question to be automatically deleted.

Comment: I don't know if the question was downvoted. It was definitly not off-topic. @robert-longsom Is there a how-to for this process? I did not fully understand your hint.

Comment: Specifically: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/282094

Comment: The proposed duplicate target is (one of) the [tag:feature-request] post(s) which resulted in resolving the issue of being able to find your own deleted posts, but I'm not comfortable closing this [tag:support] question as a duplicate of it. That question has 29 answers, which are *quite* wide-ranging in discussing the FR. While there is [a single answer](/a/374184) which describes the change SE made and show how to find the user's deleted posts, that answer is quite difficult to find on that question. IMO, we'd be better off with a *separate* canonical "how to find my deleted posts" FAQ.

Comment: @Makyen I didn't look into creating a new FAQ bullet-point, that needs a process I haven't been involved in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the author of an answer to a deleted question, [you can see the deleted question and your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511#179511) if you have the direct link to it.

You can get a link to your deleted answer by going to the "answers" tab of your profile and clicking on "Deleted answers".

If, as you assert, the question is indeed on-topic, and since the author deleted their account (and their post) just seconds after you posted your answer, I'd file a request on the per-site meta to have the question undeleted. If your answer had had enough time to be upvoted, it would have prevented the question from being deleted, as downvoted questions with upvoted answers aren't deleted upon user deletion (and the author would have been prevented from deleting it manually).